# Is it possible to change a div order one after another using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, wrapper

I am not sure how to ask this and using correct wording or not.

I have this wrapper

```
<div class="posts">

</div>
```

And I am appending two divs inside this using following jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    jQuery('.posts').append('<div class="post_entry">
                    <div class="post_thumb">
                        <img width="100%" src="' + value.better_featured_image.source_url + '" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_details">
                        <p>' + value.excerpt.rendered + '</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>');
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }

        });
```

so this will render the HTML like this.

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post_entry"> <!-- this will be repeated till how many posts have in the loop-->
        <div class="post_thumb">
            <img width="100%" src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        </div>
        <div class="post_details">
            <p>excerpt</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But what I want is 
in first post structur should be image thenn excerpt, 
second post should be excerpt and image then again 
third post sholud be image then excert then again
fourth post should be excerpt and image then again and so on...

so the rendered HTML shuould be like:

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post_entry"> 
        <div class="post_thumb">
            <img width="100%" src="image1.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        </div>
        <div class="post_details">
            <p>excerpt1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="posts">
    <div class="post_entry"> 
        <div class="post_details">
            <p>excerpt2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post_thumb">
            <img width="100%" src="image2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="posts">
    <div class="post_entry"> 
        <div class="post_thumb">
            <img width="100%" src="image3.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        </div>
        <div class="post_details">
            <p>excerpt3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="posts">
    <div class="post_entry"> 
        <div class="post_details">
            <p>excerpt4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post_thumb">
            <img width="100%" src="image4.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on..

Is it possible to get this?

Comment: So is there anything like fixed number of **posts** you are getting?

Comment: nop.. I'll be adding posts everyday.. so can not limit the number of posts..

Comment: Ok.. So For every first and fourth div element you want to change the way element gets appended right?

Comment: 1st & 3rd or 2nd & 4th.. that means 1st & 3rd HTML should be same and 2nd & 4th HTML structure should be same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

```
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            if(index % 2 == 0){
                jQuery('.posts').append('<div class="post_entry">
                <div class="post_thumb">
                    <img width="100%" src="' + value.better_featured_image.source_url + '" alt="" title="" />
                </div>
                <div class="post_details">
                    <p>' + value.excerpt.rendered + '</p>
                </div>
                </div>');
            }else{
                jQuery('.posts').append('<div class="post_entry">
                <div class="post_details">
                    <p>' + value.excerpt.rendered + '</p>
                </div>
                <div class="post_thumb">
                    <img width="100%" src="' + value.better_featured_image.source_url + '" alt="" title="" />
                </div>
                </div>');
            }   
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `append()` use `after()` or `insertAfter()`. and you can build your html format base on your array.

**it should be.**

jQuery('.posts').after('your html');

for more info please refer this [link](http://api.jquery.com/after/)